# emailing using phpmailer using post data for email address

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

im trying to email something to a user based on the email address that is entered on the html form. i am using post as the method and i cant figure out how to use that data for the email address using phpmailer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form method='post'>
<input type='email' value='@domain.com' name='emailaddress'>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'> 
</form>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) {
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail-> IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";

$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->From = "foo@bar.com";
$mail->FromName = "foo bar";
$mail->AddAddress = (HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO ENTER emailaddress FROM THE FORM);
$mail->Subject = "test1";
$mail->Body = "Test 1 of PHPMailer.";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->AddAttachment('sample.pdf','sample.pdf');
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message did not sent <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form edit:

```
<input type='email' value='@domain.com' name='emailaddress'>
```

(removed the double quote)

php edit:

```
$mail ->AddAddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
```

should do the job.

Comment: i already tried that unfortunatly and i the double quote was an accidental typo which was not in my actual code. That was an example. Thank you though

Comment: the code should work. If it is not,, ask your self if you can send mail at all. try this script and send a mail to your self. If it cant then your server doesnt support mail: <?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>

Comment: i can send mail if i put a static email address in, but if i use a variable it says i need at least recipient. all is working with smtp but it doesn't work with a post variable

Comment: use a var dumb to see if it is a string (dont know why but just 2 make sure for debugging): var_dump($_POST['emailaddress']);

Comment: $mail ->AddAddress also got a typo,, remove the space

Comment: i have got it to work as well sorry i just woke up and hadn't tried that yet buti actually was missing the () around the $_POST STATEMENT. Thank you.